# To-Do-List Delete All Function

Tags: javascript

How can I fix the function to delete all todoItems? My guess is that the for loops is not working right :\ I appreciate any help with my problem! I have only 1-month of experience with javascript.

How can I fix the function to delete all todoItems? My guess is that the for loops is not working right :\ I appreciate any help with my problem! I have only 1-month of experience with javascript.

```js
function selectColorStatus(event){
    let target = event.target;
    target.classList.toggle('todoTextSelected');
}



function createToDoItem(userInputValue){
    // To-Do Item Container
    let todoItem = document.createElement("div");
    todoItem.classList.add("row", "flx");
    todoItem.onclick = selectColorStatus;

    

    // Clear List
    let btnDeleteItem = document.getElementById('btnDeleteItem');
    btnDeleteItem.onclick = function (){
        for(let i = 0; i < todoItem; i++){
            todoItem.remove();
        }
    }

    // Inner Text
    let todoText = document.createElement('div');
    todoText.classList.add('grow');
    todoText.innerText = userInputValue;

    // Date 
    let CreateDate = document.createElement('div');
    CreateDate.classList.add('date');
    let date = new Date();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    day = date.getDay();
    CreateDate.innerText = 'Created at ' + year + '-' +  month  + '-'+ day;

    // Delete Button
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('div');
    deleteBtn.classList.add('btnDelete');
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'X';
    deleteBtn.onclick = function(){
        todoItem.remove();
    }
    
    
    todoItem.appendChild(todoText);
    todoItem.appendChild(CreateDate)
    todoItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    let todoItemsContainer = document.getElementById('todoItemsContainer');
    todoItemsContainer.appendChild(todoItem);
}

// Item Entry and Validation
function ToDoItemHandler(){
    let userInput = document.getElementById('toDoEntry');
    let userInputValue = userInput.value;
    if(userInputValue == ''){
        alert('Entry can not be empty!')
    }else{
        
        createToDoItem(userInputValue);
        userInput.value = '';
    }
}


// Add Item Button
let btnAddItem = document.getElementById('btnAddItem');
btnAddItem.onclick = ToDoItemHandler;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = './style/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>To-Do-List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'container'>
        <div id="toDoHeader">
            <h1>To-Do List</h1>
            <div id = 'toDoContent'>
                <input type = 'text' id = 'toDoEntry' name = 'toDoEntry' placeholder = 'Add item here'>
                <button type = 'button' id = 'btnAddItem' name = 'addToDoList'>Add</button>
                <button type = 'button' id = 'btnDeleteItem' name = 'deleteList'>Delete All</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="todoItemsContainer">
        </div>
    </div>


    
    <script src = './js/app.js'></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your delete function to

```
let btnDeleteItem = document.getElementById('btnDeleteItem');
  btnDeleteItem.onclick = function (){
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.row') // select all todos
      items.forEach(el => {
        el.remove() // remove each one
   })
 }
```

```js
function selectColorStatus(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      target.classList.toggle('todoTextSelected');
    }



    function createToDoItem(userInputValue) {
      // To-Do Item Container
      let todoItem = document.createElement("div");
      todoItem.classList.add("row", "flx");
      todoItem.onclick = selectColorStatus;



      // Clear List
      let btnDeleteItem = document.getElementById('btnDeleteItem');
      btnDeleteItem.onclick = function () {
        const items = document.querySelectorAll('.row')
        items.forEach(el => {
          el.remove()
        })
      }

      // Inner Text
      let todoText = document.createElement('div');
      todoText.classList.add('grow');
      todoText.innerText = userInputValue;

      // Date 
      let CreateDate = document.createElement('div');
      CreateDate.classList.add('date');
      let date = new Date();
      year = date.getFullYear();
      month = date.getMonth();
      day = date.getDay();
      CreateDate.innerText = 'Created at ' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

      // Delete Button
      let deleteBtn = document.createElement('div');
      deleteBtn.classList.add('btnDelete');
      deleteBtn.innerText = 'X';
      deleteBtn.onclick = function () {
        todoItem.remove();
      }


      todoItem.appendChild(todoText);
      todoItem.appendChild(CreateDate)
      todoItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

      let todoItemsContainer = document.getElementById('todoItemsContainer');
      todoItemsContainer.appendChild(todoItem);
    }

    // Item Entry and Validation
    function ToDoItemHandler() {
      let userInput = document.getElementById('toDoEntry');
      let userInputValue = userInput.value;
      if (userInputValue == '') {
        alert('Entry can not be empty!')
      } else {

        createToDoItem(userInputValue);
        userInput.value = '';
      }
    }


    // Add Item Button
    let btnAddItem = document.getElementById('btnAddItem');
    btnAddItem.onclick = ToDoItemHandler;
```

```html
<div id = 'container'>
      <div id="toDoHeader">
          <h1>To-Do List</h1>
          <div id = 'toDoContent'>
              <input type ='text' id='toDoEntry' name ='toDoEntry' placeholder = 'Add item here'>
              <button type ='button' id='btnAddItem' name ='addToDoList'>Add</button>
              <button type ='button' id='btnDeleteItem' name ='deleteList'>Delete All</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="todoItemsContainer">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do:

```js
// Clear List
let btnDeleteItem = document.getElementById('btnDeleteItem');
btnDeleteItem.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('todoItemsContainer').innerHTML = ''
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you. That is a very simple solution. I guess I need more experience with JS!